# Private blockchain on AWS stuck on Looking for peers

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, aws, geth-clique

I am running 3 nodes private blockchain network on AWS with Clique(POA) consensus. One is `bootnode` and others are `miner` nodes.

Here is my `blockchainpoa.json`

```json
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 14333,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 10,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x63787819",
  "extraData": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003d49f67d6da491e15843dc9689fe8ebd6abd2f5e5c6adc6295aeb1c0246888915a9130552397daaf0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000005": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000006": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000007": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000009": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000010": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000011": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000012": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000013": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000014": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000015": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000016": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000017": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000018": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000019": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000020": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000021": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000022": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000023": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000024": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000025": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000026": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000027": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000028": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000029": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000030": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000031": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000032": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000033": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000034": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000035": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000036": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000037": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000038": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000039": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000040": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000041": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000042": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000043": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000044": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000045": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000046": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000047": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000048": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000049": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000050": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000051": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000052": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000053": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000054": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000055": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000056": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000057": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000058": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000059": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000060": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000061": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000062": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000063": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000064": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000065": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000066": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000067": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000068": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000069": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000070": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000071": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000072": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000073": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000074": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000075": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000076": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000077": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000078": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000079": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000080": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000081": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000082": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000083": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000084": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000085": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000086": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000087": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000088": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000089": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000090": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000091": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000092": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000093": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000094": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000095": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000096": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000097": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000098": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000099": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000aa": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ab": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ac": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ad": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ae": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000af": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ba": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000be": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bf": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ca": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ce": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cf": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000da": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000db": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000dc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000dd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000de": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000df": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ea": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000eb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ec": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ed": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ee": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ef": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fa": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fe": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ff": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "1221df463e8000d8fabcec92a92743e194e776d6": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "3d49f67d6da491e15843dc9689fe8ebd6abd2f5e": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "5c6adc6295aeb1c0246888915a9130552397daaf": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "5da1933ada437b00f9244e70f631719d8e204606": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "a4db61d58264645dbf096825e3b77ac5d7703301": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "baseFeePerGas": null
}
```

The bootnode is started with the following shell script `bootnode.sh`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

bootnode -nodekey ./boot.key -verbosity 7 -addr 0.0.0.0:30301 > node1.log 2>&1 & disown
# Sleep for 5 seconds so that the bootnode process can start before we exit the
# script.
sleep 5
echo $! > bootnode.pid
echo "Bootnode started"
```

The node2 is started with following shell script `node2.sh`. I run this script by passing the bootnode IP address like: `./node2.sh <IP-address-of-bootnode>`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize the geth node.
geth --datadir ./data init blockchainpoa.json

# Start the geth node.
geth --networkid 14333 --datadir ./data --bootnodes "enode://71f642afabf03a48cce35e96dfb4cd4a32333b0eae78c1d8b9651d3fa132fb1131e49b2b8ddfe0bf45f9e4ef388972920182e6782d11f5df00f6da010a78c6c4@$1:0?discport=30301" \
--port 30310 \
--ipcdisable \
--syncmode 'full' \
--allow-insecure-unlock \
--unlock '0x5c6ADc6295aEB1c0246888915a9130552397daAf,0xf3c6284Cb2142a84f36f6e2AF2C6287b343dCf3f' \
--password password.txt \
--mine \
--http \
--http.corsdomain "*" \
--http.addr 0.0.0.0 \
--http.port 8545 \
--http.api="admin,debug,web3,eth,txpool,personal,miner,net" \
--ws \
--ws.origins="*" \
--ws.addr 0.0.0.0 \
--ws.port 8546 \
--ws.api="admin,debug,web3,eth,txpool,personal,miner,net,clique" \
--authrpc.port 8551 > node2.log 2>&1 & disown

# Sleep for 5 seconds so that the geth process can start before we exit the
# script.
sleep 5
echo "Geth Node 2 started"
```

The node3 is started with following shell script `node3.sh`. I run this script by passing the bootnode IP address like: `./node3.sh <IP-address-of-bootnode>`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize the geth node.
geth --datadir ./data init blockchainpoa.json

# Start the geth node.
geth --networkid 14333 --datadir ./data --bootnodes "enode://71f642afabf03a48cce35e96dfb4cd4a32333b0eae78c1d8b9651d3fa132fb1131e49b2b8ddfe0bf45f9e4ef388972920182e6782d11f5df00f6da010a78c6c4@$1:0?discport=30301" \
--port 30311 \
--ipcdisable \
--syncmode 'full' \
--allow-insecure-unlock \
--unlock '0x5c6ADc6295aEB1c0246888915a9130552397daAf,0xf3c6284Cb2142a84f36f6e2AF2C6287b343dCf3f' \
--password password.txt \
--mine \
--http \
--http.corsdomain "*" \
--http.addr 0.0.0.0 \
--http.port 8547 \
--http.api="admin,debug,web3,eth,txpool,personal,miner,net" \
--ws \
--ws.origins="*" \
--ws.addr 0.0.0.0 \
--ws.port 8548 \
--ws.api="admin,debug,web3,eth,txpool,personal,miner,net,clique" \
--authrpc.port 8552 > node3.log 2>&1 & disown

# Sleep for 5 seconds so that the geth process can start before we exit the
# script.
sleep 5
echo "Geth Node 3 started"
```

**The Output:**

`tail -f bootnode.log` gives me the following output:

```sh
TRACE[11-26|19:12:44.075] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=0e9624b062108233 addr=3.83.139.220:30310 err=nil
TRACE[11-26|19:12:44.075] >> NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=0e9624b062108233 addr=3.83.139.220:30310 err=nil
TRACE[11-26|19:12:44.428] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=eec34091a4b54fe1 addr=54.158.49.42:30311 err=nil
TRACE[11-26|19:12:44.429] >> NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=eec34091a4b54fe1 addr=54.158.49.42:30311 err=nil
TRACE[11-26|19:12:44.576] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=0e9624b062108233 addr=3.83.139.220:30310 err=nil
TRACE[11-26|19:12:44.576] >> NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=0e9624b062108233 addr=3.83.139.220:30310 err=nil
```

`tail -f node2.log` gives me the following output:

```sh
INFO [11-26|19:02:23.810] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
INFO [11-26|19:02:33.831] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
INFO [11-26|19:02:39.159] Commit new sealing work                  number=2 sealhash=5bbbf6..81d784 uncles=0 txs=3 gas=63000 fees=6.3e-05 elapsed="551.982µs"
WARN [11-26|19:02:39.159] Block sealing failed                     err="signed recently, must wait for others"


INFO [11-26|19:02:43.852] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
INFO [11-26|19:02:53.873] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
INFO [11-26|19:03:03.892] Looking for peers
```

`tail -f node3.log` gives me the following output:

```
INFO [11-26|18:40:53.682] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1,000,000,000
INFO [11-26|18:40:53.682] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0x5c6ADc6295aEB1c0246888915a9130552397daAf
INFO [11-26|18:40:53.683] Commit new sealing work                  number=2 sealhash=623297..acf7c1 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="163.266µs"
WARN [11-26|18:40:53.684] Block sealing failed                     err="signed recently, must wait for others"
INFO [11-26|18:40:53.684] Commit new sealing work                  number=2 sealhash=a09993..f0eed0 uncles=0 txs=1 gas=21000 fees=2.1e-05 elapsed=1.938ms
WARN [11-26|18:40:53.685] Block sealing failed                     err="signed recently, must wait for others"
INFO [11-26|18:41:01.741] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=1 static=0


INFO [11-26|18:41:11.763] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
INFO [11-26|18:41:21.787] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
INFO [11-26|18:41:31.809] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
```

**Looks like my node2 and node3 are not able to connect to each other but they are able to connect with bootnode. I also tried with `admin.addPeers` by passing the enode of each others but still I am not able to add peer nodes.**

In AWS security group I have allowed `ALL` the traffic on all 3 nodes but still I am not able to connect. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You've allowed all inbound or outbound traffic in your security group? It's ok to allow all outboud traffic, but allowing all inbound traffic is dangerous. You should only open the inbound ports that you need.

Comment: @Undead8 I am just doing it for learning purposes, It's not in production.